# Reading Google Trends time series data with Python

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm trying to read the following URL into Python:

```
http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=nepal&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3
```

with the code:

```
trend_url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=nepal&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3'        
response = urllib2.urlopen(trend_url)
the_page = response.read()
```

The resulting value of the_page, for reasons that I don't understand, is an error page.

**UPDATE:** I think that the problem is related to some authentication issue: when I try to open the link in the browser's incognito window, it also returns an error page.

Answer (score 1):

use `requests`

```
import requests
a = requests.get('http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=nepal&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3')
a.text
```

`u'// Data table response\ngoogle.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"` ....

---

I tested your example and it is works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've edited the question to include more details.

Comment: details? it's work for me even using a browser in incognito mode. Maybe you done to many requests in a short amount of time, maybe an anti-bot mechanism from google.

Answer (score 0):

I think is kinda late, but I think that Google does that in order to protect their data. You have to create a web-scraping that will go to the interface put the word you want, and it will generate the page/url. That is not the same as going at first sight for the URL generated.